# Check if DynamoDB table Empty

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a `dynamoDB` table and I want to check if there are any items in it (using python). In other words, return `true` is the table is empty.

I am not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using Scan**

The best way is to scan and check the count. You might be using `boto3` AWS sdk for python.Use the `scan` function to scan the whole table and get the count.This may not be costly as you are scanning the table only once and it would not scan the entire table.
A single scan returns only 1 MB of data, so it would not be time consuming.

Read the docs for more details : [Boto3 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html)

**Using describe table**

This could be helpful as well to get the count but

> DynamoDB updates this value approximately every six hours. Recent changes might not be reflected in this value.

so this could be only used if you don't want the most recent updated value.
Read the docs for more details : [describe table dynamodb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply take the count of that particular table using [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html), which is the AWS SDK for Python:

```
import boto3        

def table_is_empty(table_name):

    dynamo_resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamo_resource.Table(table_name)

    return table.item_count == 0
```

Note that the values are updated periodically and the result might not be precise:

> The number of items in the specified index. DynamoDB updates this
>   value approximately every six hours. Recent changes might not be
>   reflected in this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Describe table function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.describe_table) from `boto3` in the response you can get the number of items that are in the table as you can see in the response example on the link.

Part of the command response:

```
    'TableSizeBytes': 123,
    'ItemCount': 123,
    'TableArn': 'string',
    'TableId': 'string',
```

As said in the comments, the vaule is updated aproximately every 6h, so recent changes may not be updated.

Comment: this won't be helpful as the value gets updated after every 6 hours [read this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/describe-table.html)